# Create proportional tables of a single variable with a list of variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

This is probably a very easy question, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I created a proportional table of two variables:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, carb)%>%
  summarise(n=n())%>%
  mutate(prop=n/sum(n))%>%
  subset(select=c("cyl", "carb", "prop"))%>%
  spread(cyl, prop)%>%
  kable()
```

Now I want to create multiple tables with cyl as one variable and looping through a list of multiple variables for the second variable. This was one approach I tried that didn't work:

```
cols = c('vs', 'am', 'gear', 'carb')
for (q in cols) {
  map2(~prop.table(table(mtcars[[q]], mtcars[["cyl"]])))
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,  we can use `map` to loop over the 'cols' instead of `for` + `map2` to return a `list` of output

```
library(purrr)
lst1 <-  map(cols, ~ prop.table(table(mtcars[[.x]], mtcars[["cyl"]])))
lst1
#[[1]]

#          4       6       8
#  0 0.03125 0.09375 0.43750
#  1 0.31250 0.12500 0.00000

#[[2]]

#          4       6       8
#  0 0.09375 0.12500 0.37500
#  1 0.25000 0.09375 0.06250

#[[3]]

#          4       6       8
#  3 0.03125 0.06250 0.37500
#  4 0.25000 0.12500 0.00000
#  5 0.06250 0.03125 0.06250

#[[4]]

#          4       6       8
#  1 0.15625 0.06250 0.00000
#  2 0.18750 0.00000 0.12500
#  3 0.00000 0.00000 0.09375
#  4 0.00000 0.12500 0.18750
#  6 0.00000 0.03125 0.00000
#  8 0.00000 0.00000 0.03125
```

---

If we want to use the `tidyverse` functions

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
map(cols, ~ mtcars %>%
               group_by_at(vars(cyl, .x)) %>%
               summarise(n = n()) %>%
               mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>% 
               select(cyl, !!.x, prop) %>%
               pivot_wider(names_from = cyl, values_from = prop))
```

Comment: Both options worked great! And thanks for showing it two ways.